# Как самым простым способом достать данные из Json?

Tags: c#, json

Есть такая небольшая Json строка

```
{"domain": "fenixrostov.ru", 
"success": "error", 
"error": "occupied"}
```

Как мне достать значение поля error, без создание классов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С использованием [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var json =
    "{\"domain\": \"fenixrostov.ru\", " +
    "\"success\": \"error\", " +
    "\"error\": \"occupied\"}";
```

Через метод `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var error = (string)obj.error;
```

ну или через `JObject`, имеющийся в том-же пакете:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var error = (string)jobject["error"];
```